# Visual Studio Code Installation Error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I get the below error while trying to install Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of code:
 code depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4:amd64 is not configured yet.
```

How do I go about configuring libgconf2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't ship with gconf2. Following the below steps  helped resolve the issue.

1) Download and install [gconf2-common (3.2.6-4ubuntu1)](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/arm64/gconf2-common/3.2.6-4ubuntu1)

```
sudo dpkg -i gconf2-common_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_all.deb
```

2) Download and install [libgconf-2-4_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/universe/base/libgconf-2-4)

```
sudo dpkg -i libgconf-2-4_3.2.6-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

3) Install Visual Studio Code.

```
sudo dpkg -i code_1.24.1-1528912196_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and then trying to install the Visual Studio Code package again?